# is this function integrable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Here are two

i) Let $
g:[c,d] \to R
$ be continuous and $
f:[a,b] \to [c,d]
$ integrable , then $
g\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right):[a,b] \to R
$ it´s also integrable.

ii) $
f:[a,b] \to [c,d]
$, $
f \in C^1 
$, $
f´\left( x \right) \ne 0
$ for every x $
 \in [a,b]
$ and $
g:[c,d] \to R
$ integrable, then again $
g\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right)
$ it´s integrable on [a,b]

How can I do this problem, I suppose that the characterization under measure of the discontinuity set, will help, but I don´t know how to use it <.< , sorry for ask this basic things, but I´m starting to learn

Comment: In the second problem, the conditions imply that $f$ is strictly monotone, hence invertible and the inverse is strictly monotone and $\mathcal{C}^1$. Do you have any results about whether how such functions (perhaps on finite closed intervals) work on sets of measure $0$? If you can prove that the inverse image under $f$ of the points of discontinuity of $g$ is a null set you'll get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

The first: If $f(x)$ is continuous in $x_0$, then $g(f(x))$ is also continuous in this point as $g(x)$ is continuous (Theorem about composite function). It leads to statement: points of discontinuity $g(f(x))$ can be only points of discontinuity $f(x)$. But as $f(x)$ is integrable, it has Lebesgue measure of its points of discontinuity (Lebesgue integrability condition) equal to $0$ $\Rightarrow$ $g(f(x))$ has Lebesgue measure of its points of discontinuity equal to $0$. It means that $g(f(x))$ is integrable (Lebesgue integrability condition). QED.

The second: As $g(x)$ is integrable then its Lebesgue measure of its points of discontinuity equal $0$, as $f(x)$ is monotonic ($f'(x)\not=0$) then $f^{-1}$ exists on $[c,d]$ and its also monotonic (Theorem about inverse function). It means that each point of discontinuity has single inverse image point on $[a,b]$. If the set of points of discontinuity $g(x)$ has measure zero, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can cover this set by countable number of intervals of total length $(tl_1)$$<\epsilon$. Then let's get center of some interval ($I_k$) and find its inverse image, and cover this point $(x_0)$ by the interval of length $=2\frac{\text{length}(I_1)}{|f'(x_0)|}$, then do it with every interval, so now we have covering of set of discontinuity point $g(f(x))$ by countable number of intervals, let's check its total length $(tl_2)$,$tl_2<=2*tl_1/\min[|f'(x)|]=C*tl_1$; $(f'(x)$ is continuous and $f'(x)\not=0$ => for any $x$ from segment $|f'(x)|>r>0$). It leads to $g(f(x))$ Lebesgue measure of its points of discontinuity equal to $0$ $\Rightarrow$ $g(f(x))$ is integrable (Lebesgue integrability condition)

Comment: Not every set that is bijectable with a set of measure zero is of measure zero (e.g., the cantor set is bijectable with the entire unit interval),  so there is a bit of work to be done beyond "each point of discontinuity has a single inverse image point on $[a,b]$", I think...

Comment: Yeh, I understood. It'll be fixed.

Comment: @SavinovEvgeny Thanks!, but I have a question about the second problem, How can I prove that the second really cover , all the points of discontinuity, and Why you choosed this length to do it. I don´t understand nothing )=

Comment: if we get some segment [p,q] which length is sufficiently small $f:[p,q]->[f(p),f(q)]$. Using the theorem of Lagrange $f(p)-f(q)=f'(r)*(p-q)$ and $r$ belongs to $(p,q)$, then $\frac{|p-q|}{|f(p)-f(q)|}=\frac{1}{|f'(r)|}<2\frac{1}{|f'(\frac{p+q}{2})|}$ (We can say it because $f'(x)$ is continuous)

Comment: The fact that you can cover by this method follows from bijectable and continous function $f(x)$

Comment: Let's point $x_0$ that is belong to discontiunuty set of $g(x)$. Imagine where will it dysplay. $x_0 -> f^{-1}(x_0)$